# Parse list of dicts from a pandas Series into columns

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a pandas series containing a list of dictionaries. I'd like to parse the contents of the dicts with some condition and store the results into new columns.

Here's some data to work with:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'d': [[{'br': 1, 'ba': 1, 'r': 100},
                         {'ba': 1, 'r': 80},
                         {'br': 2, 'ba': 1, 'r': 150},
                         {'br': 1, 'ba': 1, 'r': 90}],
                        [{'br': 1, 'ba': 1, 'r': 100},
                         {'ba': 1, 'r': 80},
                         {'br': 2, 'ba': 1, 'r': 150}]],

                   'id': ['xxas', 'yxas'],

                   'name': [A, B]

                 })
```

I'd like to parse the contents of each dictionary with some conditional logic. Check for each dicts in the list and name columns as keys `br` and `ba`. Get the `value` of `r` `key` as assign as column value. If key is not found, `br` in this example, assign `0` as the value. Expected output:

```
id     br  ba  r     name
xxas   1   0   100   A
xxas   0   1   80    A
xxas   2   1   150   A
xxas   1   1   90    A
yxas   1   1   100   B
yxas   0   1   80    B
yxas   2   1   150   B
```

Comment: the syntax of your df is incorrect

Comment: @Kenan should be fixed.

Comment: The `df` syntax is corrected ;)

Answer (score 2):

From your `DataFrame`, we first set the columns `id` and `name` as index like so :

```py
df = df.set_index(['id', 'name'])
```

Then, we can use [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to get the expected result :

```py
pd.concat(df.d.apply(pd.DataFrame).tolist(), keys=df.index).reset_index(level=[0, 1]).reset_index(drop=True).fillna(0).rename(columns={'level_0': 'id', 'level_1': 'name'})
```

Output :

```
    id      name    br      ba  r
0   xxas    A       1.0     1   100
1   xxas    A       0.0     1   80
2   xxas    A       2.0     1   150
3   xxas    A       1.0     1   90
4   yxas    B       1.0     1   100
5   yxas    B       0.0     1   80
6   yxas    B       2.0     1   150
```

Comment: running into a few issues. I'd like `id` to be a column and not an `index` of the DataFrame. I have modified the `id` column to be a `string` instead of an `integer`. Also, I have additional columns in the DataFrame that I'd like to include as well.

Comment: Hi @kms, I took in consideration the columns changes and the non index id as requested in your comment. I wish you a great day !